# Error while creating an exe file from a py project

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to obtain a linux exe from a python project.
I've created a file .spec, modified it according my configuration (I suppose) but I get following error when `run pyinstaller index.spec`

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyinstaller-4.1-py3.5.egg/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 720, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyinstaller-4.1-py3.5.egg/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 667, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "index.spec", line 18, in <module>
    noarchive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyinstaller-4.1-py3.5.egg/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 253, in __init__
    for name, pth in format_binaries_and_datas(datas, workingdir=spec_dir):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyinstaller-4.1-py3.5.egg/PyInstaller/building/utils.py", line 484, in format_binaries_and_datas
    for src_root_path_or_glob, trg_root_dir in binaries_or_datas:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

and this is the file .spec. Its the first time I try build an exe so Im not sure the file .spec is correct

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['index.py', 'calendar_draw.py','extract_draw.py','library.py','pezzoli_draw.py','ciminiere_draw.py',
'functions.py','makepdf_draw.py','projectr_draw.py','educat_draw.py','global_draw.py','makepdfhour_data.py','tirocinanti_draw.py','extract_data.py','index.py','perma_draw.py'],
             pathex=['/opt/mambo'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=['fs.png','fsu.png','garnet.png','gg.png','logo_mambo.png','ohio.png','logo_auser.jpg'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='index',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='index')
```